# C# winforms - which are the scenarios where Form.ActiveForm = null?

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I have a c# winforms app (MyApp.exe) running on Raspberry Pi via Mono.

MyApp starts with:
`Application.Run(new FormHome());`

I open the following forms with:

```
FormX formX = new FormX();
formX.Show();
```

And I close them with:
`formX.Close();`

I assume that MyApp is always in focus (Or maybe it's not and this is the answer to my question?)

But let's suppose MyApp is always in focus,
then which are the possible scenarios where there is no active form?

Can it be that `Form.ActiveForm` gets assigned to `null` in the transaction of Deactivating FormA and Activating FormB?

Comment: `formX.Hide();`

Comment: Something in your app that isn't a form or lives on a form that has the focus?  Like a non winforms systemdialog?

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activeform?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ActiveForm):

> Active Form - A Form that represents the currently active form, or
> null if there is no active form.

If none of the forms belonging to the application have focus, then the active form will be null.

So if we're assuming your app is always in focus you will never have ActiveForm = null.